# Compute the probability that the Markov chain $(X_n)_{n≥0}$ starting from state 1 will eventually reach state 3.

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

**Problem:**

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a Markov Chain on the state space $S=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ with transition probability matrix given by:

$$P=\begin{bmatrix} 
1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/3 & 2/3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Compute the probability that the Markov chain $(X_n)_{n≥0}$ starting from state 1 will eventually reach state 3.

**Attempt:**

Well, i guess there are multiple ways to get to state 3 when starting from state 1, depending on the way one go. But it's the 'eventually' that really confuses me...

Any hints?

Comment: From state $1$ you can either stay or go to state $2$. Finally from state $2$ you can either stay or go to state $3$. Thus, in order to not get to state $3$ starting from state $1$, you need to loop indefinitely at one of the previous states. Hence the probability of starting at state $1$ and not reaching state $3$ is easy to compute and allows you to compute the probability you are actually interested in.

Comment: I've heard what you've said, and i think i have idea:

$P_1(\tau_3 <\infty)$ denotes the probability of hitting state 3 starting from state 1, i.e.:

$$P_1(\tau_3 <\infty)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_{1,3}^{(n)}P_3(\tau_3 < \infty)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_{1,3}^{(n)}\cdot 1=p_{1,3}^{(1)}+p_{1,3}^{(2)}+p_{1,3}^{(3)}+...=$$

But notice that there is zero probability that $1 \rightarrow 3$ because, state $1$ can't go to  state $3$ in $1-$jump. Therefore $p_{1,3}^{(1)}=0$ which gives

$$P_1(\tau_3<\infty)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Sounds good?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what all your notation is supposed to mean. What I meant to say is that if you are not reaching state $3$ starting from $1$ means that you either get stuck at state $1$ (i.e. infinitely often you decide to stay at state $1$ instead of moving on to state $2$) or you are getting stuck at state $2$. For the later you have more options, you can either loop a couple of times at state $1$ and then move on to $2$ and then loop at state $2$ forever. If your notation is meant to express this, then yes :)